# SVG to VML or bitmap at loadtime

Tags: svg, cross-browser, vml, load-time

Maybe this question doesn't have a simple answer.

I would like to use SVG for most of the graphics on my website but of course there will be the usual (IE) compatibility problem.

So I was wondering, is there a way to render SVG images as VML or bitmap on browsers that don't support it? The system should work for img tags and for CSS backgrounds files.

Better would be if the system is client side, so that it could be used whatever framework is used on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this helps but the following says something about converting SVG to VML:

[SVG coords to VML coords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811492/svg-coords-to-vml-coords)

As for the bitmap conversion, can you save two versions of the image. One as SVG and one as bitmap and if the browser doesn't have SVG compatablity, fallback on the bitmap version?